# Bootstrap Column Grid Conversion

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sx-12">
    <div class="top-share pull-right">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

I'm using bootstrap framework.  How to use bootstrap column or grid system?

I'm using `col-md-3`, `col-md-4`,  `col-md-6`,  `col-md-8`, `col-md-9`,  etc. in various situation.  I want to know what column  will have   when I'll  use `col-sm`, and `col-xs`  respectively for `col-md-3`, `col-md-4`,  `col-md-6`,  `col-md-8`, and `col-md-9`. Basically conversion of grid.

Comment: In bootstrap have 5 type of grid options
As use of specific device as our needs
col-xs- (extra small device)
col-sm- (small device)
col-md- (medium device)
col-lg- (large device)

check this link may be you get idea : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**xs** `/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */`

**sm** `/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }`

**md** `/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }`

**lg** `/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }`

In fact, Bootstrap is mobile first.
For example, you have two blocks of content on large screens:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
  // your code here...
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
  // your code here...
</div>
```

on small screens devices it'll look weird! in this case `xs`-class helps you!

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
  // your code here...
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
  // your code here...
</div>
```

it means, before screen-width is `1200px`, each block takes full width of screen. when screen-width is `1200px` and more, each block takes half of full screen-width

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
  // your code here...
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
  // your code here...
</div>
```

in this case, each block takes half of full screen-width when screen-width is `992px` or more

Comment: @Hasan What about you always asking?

Comment: Thank you very much @ Lgor Lvancha

Answer (score 0):

**Bootstrap Grid System**
Bootstrap's grid system allows up to `12 columns` across the page.

If you do not want to use all 12 column individually, you can group the columns together to create wider columns:

**Grid Classes**
The Bootstrap grid system has four classes:

```
xs (for phones)

sm (for tablets)

md (for desktops)

lg (for larger desktops)
```

The classes above can be combined to create more dynamic and flexible layouts.

**Basic Structure of a Bootstrap Grid**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-*-*"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-*-*"></div>
    <div class="col-*-*"></div>
    <div class="col-*-*"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

[Learn more about it](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)

Comment: Ok I understand. But If i use col-md-3 what it is for col-sm or col-xs or col-lg ? tnkx

Comment: Use the extra small and medium device grid classes by adding `col-xs- .col-md-`  to your columns.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) link to know about bootstrap grid system and how to use it.